# Android Server communication asynchronously

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am working on an asynchronous client server application. After a request is made to a server asynchronously, I should process the message and send back to the client. To receive the response from the server asynchronously, the client should have a sort of RESTful server. Are there any libraries or APIs I can use on android client?
Thanx

Comment: use asynctask for this purpose

Answer (score 4):

Use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) by [Square](http://square.github.io/).

(From the site:)

### Introduction

Retrofit turns your REST API into a Java interface.

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

The `RestAdapter` class generates an implementation of the `GitHubService` interface.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .build();
```

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);
Each call on the generated `GitHubService` makes an HTTP request to the remote webserver.

```
List<Repo> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

Use annotations to describe the HTTP request:

URL parameter replacement and query parameter support
Object conversion to request body (e.g., JSON, protocol buffers)
Multipart request body and file upload

Also try to avoid `AsyncTask`, this is a good read on the subject: [Robust and readable architecture for an Android App](http://blog.joanzapata.com/robust-architecture-for-an-android-app/?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=2128dc7e77-Android_Weekly_99&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-2128dc7e77-337837333)

Comment: They are using Android Service, I think its not for short term operation like validating user from server.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a short or long term operation, using AsyncTask can cause memory leaks. This library is a great library for REST API which is what the user asked for, whether it's for user validation or whatever, it's robust enough to handle whatever.

Comment: Ok thanks for infromation. i  have upvoted you Answer.

Comment: You are welcome, and thanks for the upvote (although I don't see an upvote) :) Have great day.

Comment: Sorry for delay vated... :)

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know AsyncTask can cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually don't use Asynctask - it's lacks important features needed for a proper network framework (or you just sit and develop them yourself for hours)

[Google developed Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) for that in 2013:

- Volley automatically schedule all network requests. It means that Volley will be taking care of all the network requests your app executes for fetching response or image from web.
- Volley provides transparent disk and memory caching.
- Volley provides powerful cancellation request API. It means that you can cancel a single request or you can set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel. Volley provides powerful customization abilities.
- Volley provides Debugging and tracing tools

(from: [Android – Volley Library Example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library))

Resources

- [Google IO 13 presentation](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728)
- [Official Google Repo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley)
- [Github mirror](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

Gradle Dependency

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Asynctask is actually a bad choice for using as a network framwork in every use case than the most trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement code like this:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog=null;   

private class LoadApi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", 
                            "Please wait...");
                        super.onPreExecute();
                    }

                    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                        //Do your api call stuff here
                        return null;
                    }
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        handle response from api call here.
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsyncTask` for the same,

here is official documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I am also giving you an example of Asyntask.

```
class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{
    protected void onPreExecute (){
        Log.d("ASYNCTASK","On pre Exceute......");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
        Log.d("ASYNCTASK","In On doInBackground...");
 // make request RESTful service here.
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Integer in = new Integer(i);
            publishProgress(i);  // Update your Ui
        }
        return "You are in PostExecute";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a){
        Log.d("ASYNTASK","You are in progress update ... " + a[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // here you can perform all action after getting resonances from RESTful service
        Log.d(""+result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed a external library for http services.You can use Android Asynchronous Http Client

> http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

downloaded the jar file from the link use this method

```
public void getData(String URL)
{

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.setTimeout(30000);
    client.get(URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onSuccess(arg0);


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);



        }

    });
}
```

You got the result as a string in the onsucess.
in your manifest file u have to given the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: have to got the result